Jetty tmp Multipart files not being deleted after upload
I have a question regarding the files Jetty temporarily stores in disk during an upload.
As far as I understand, during the upload of some Multipart files, Jetty actually stores in disk these files during the duration of the upload and then the files should be removed automatically from this temporary directory.
My issue is that these files don't ever get deleted, and end up exhausting our free available disk space.
Has anyone encountered anything similar, or have any idea how this could be fixed?
We are using Jetty v12.0.10 provided via SpringBoot.
I know that there are some config properties to define the max size you want to store in mem vs in disk in Spring, like the file-size-threshold (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/appendix/application-properties/index.html#application-properties.web.spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold) but I do not think this is the proper solution, since we would be creating other problems.
Thanks!

So when working with Async requests, it seems there was a bug and it will be corrected in version 6.1.12. Have a look here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/33161

Same problem occured to me, although I am not using Spring Boot, just Spring Framework. The root cause was that I did not have bean named multipartResolver (constant DispatcherServlet.MULTIPART_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME) in my Spring ApplicationContext.
Without this bean, multipart uploads worked fine, but without cleaning the files after request.
During initialization of DispatcherServlet, method initMultipartResolver searches for bean named multipartResolver. In my case, it did not find it and initialized multipartResolver to null. Because of that, methods checkMultipart and cleanupMultipart did not do any work.
I defined the bean using this configuration (kotlin):
@Bean(name = [DispatcherServlet.MULTIPART_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME])
open fun multipartResolver(): MultipartResolver = StandardServletMultipartResolver()


It seems the Bean was already being resolved properly, but thanks to your answer I could have a look and debug what was happening inside the DispatcherServlet.
So it seems the cleanup method is never called. We are handling the request asynchronously, and when it is completed, the multipartRequestParsed flag is set to false which never triggers the code we need. I'll keep having a look on the reason why this is happening.
